# What am I missing with this failed, C++ string comparison?

Tags: c++, string, binary-search-tree

I am trying to compare a string with a binary search tree, and the below code works on the very first one, but then fails on every other one--even though I have checked to make sure it is recursively checking the tree. Thanks!

```
bool BST::compareIt(Node* current, string name)
{
    if (name == current->title)
       return true;
    if (current->left != NULL)
        compareIt(current->left, name);
    if (current->right != NULL)
        compareIt(current->right, name);
    return false;
 }
```

I

Comment: Personally, I don't like using string.. I use char* instead...

Comment: @mlwn why is that? What's wrong with string?

Comment: Most of the time, I code for limited processors, and I like to control the memory used... I guess nothing wrong with string on modern machines

Comment: @mlwn That's interesting, but not likely to help clarify this question or help readers of this question.

Comment: @aschepler ... I even up voted your comment... You're right..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return the result of your recursive calls, e.g.

```
if (current->left != NULL)
    return compareIt(current->left, name);
```

and similarly for the right hand branch.

Comment: You are a godsend. The obvious what in front of me and I didn't see it. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: No worries, happens to everyone. Consider accepting the answer if it works for you.